# DNS mask over LAN to redirect domain to local ip

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, dnsmasq

I am trying to setup a `DNS MASK` to route over LAN like this: `client requests https//example.com:4430` to be routed to `server https://192.168.1.80:443`

DNS mask is running on the server

I point my client to DNS 8.8.8.8 and try to access `https//example.com:4430`

on my server `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
interface=eth0
domain-needed         
bogus-priv            
no-poll              
no-resolv             
cache-size=150 
server=8.8.8.8
address=/example.com/192.168.1.80
```

my server `/etc/hosts/`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 cloud
example.com
```

my server apache conf file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/nc-access.log combined
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/nc-error.log
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
 </VirtualHost>
 <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride All
 <IfModule mod_dav.c>
  Dav off
 </IfModule>
  LimitRequestBody 0
  SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
 </Directory>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost *:4430>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/nc-access.log combined
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/nc-error.log
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
 </VirtualHost>
 <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 AllowOverride All
 <IfModule mod_dav.c>
  Dav off
 </IfModule>
 LimitRequestBody 0
 SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
 </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your `dnsmasq` instance you should make your client point your server and not `8.8.8.8` (or do a DNAT on the client router).

DNS is not enough to do what you want (redirect https//example.com:4430 to https://192.168.1.80:443) because DNS can "change" the address but **can't** "change" the port. So your `*:4430` virtualhost should reply with a *redirect* to the port `443` in order to make it work.

An alternative to this is to do just a `DNAT` on the client router natting `example_ip:4430` to `server_ip:443`.